# Warum sagt man "(ein)mal abgesehen von"

Tags: word-usage

Woher kommt das Wort (ein)mal und welche Funktion erfüllt es im Satz. Z.B:

> Mal abgesehen davon,....
>
> Wenn wir einmal davon absehen,....
>
> Es läuft eben nicht, sieht man einmal vom besseren Außenauftritt Europas ab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Das Wort [*einmal*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/einmal_irgendwann_frueher) und das Wort [*mal*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mal#Bedeutung2) werden im Duden als teilweise synonym gehandelt. Dabei glaube ich (ohne es zu Wissen), dass das Wort *einmal* dabei von *mal* abstammt, im Sinne von 1 * x, aber zur Unterscheidung von dem [*Mal*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mal_Zeitpunkt) und dem *[Mahl](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Mahl)* (die früher identisch geschrieben wurden) heute zusammen geschrieben wird.

Das Wort *mal* ist eigentlich ganz gut zu verstehen, wenn man es gedanklich durch 1 * ersetzt. Dabei gibt es aber natürlich doch Unterschiede, wie auch in deinen Beispielen.

> Mal abgesehen davon, dass...

Umschreiben würde ich das mit *Sehen wir jetzt allerdings davon ab, dass ....* oder *Wenn man den Fall ausnimmt, dass*... .
Hier tritt das Wort *mal* auch irgendwie als 1 * auf, im Sinne von 
*Wir haben es bisher soundso betrachtet. Einmal, nämlich jetzt, wollen wir von ... absehen, und stellen fest, dass ...*

Natürlich ist es etwas schwer, ein Wort wie *mal* zu erklären. Die Bedeutung ergibt sich wohl besser, wenn man noch andere Beispiele betrachtet:

> Ich habe mal 90 Kilo gewogen.

*Es gab einen Zeitpunkt in meinem Leben, zu dem ich 90 Kilo gewogen habe.*

> Wir sollten mal wieder etwas unternehmen.
>
> Mal hat man Glück, mal hat man Pech.

Hier wird die Nähe zum Wort *manchmal* deutlich. *Mal* kann also nicht nur 1 * bedeuten, sondern kann auch beliebige Wiederholungen zulassen, sozusagen x * (widerum nicht zu verwechseln mit [x-mal](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/x_mal)).

Man merkt, dass die ganzheitliche Erfassung des Wortes *mal* nicht ganz einfach ist, da es viele unterschiedliche Verwendungsmöglichkeiten gibt. Ich würde es wohl am Ehesten beschreiben als Sammelwort für *einmal, zweimal, mehrmals, manchmal* etc. Wenn man daran mehr Interesse hat, sucht man am Besten Beispiele in der Literatur.

Nach gewissem Abschweifen noch einmal direkter zu deiner Frage:

*Einmal* ist also quasi ein Spezialfall von *mal*, der im Kontext das gleiche bedeuten kann, aber im Zweifelsfall genauer ist. Die Bedeutung von [*(ein)mal davon absehen*](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/absehen#Bedeutung4) ist eigentlich im Duden ganz gut erklärt.

Hilft dir das alles nicht, dann vielleicht Übersetzungen in andere Sprachen:

> Once I was at the top of that hill. 
>   Ich war (ein)mal auf der Spitze dieses Berges.
>
> Una volta la pizza qui non era buona. 
>   Einmal war die Pizza hier nicht gut.

EDIT: Ich vergaß zu erwähnen, dass die Verwendung von *mal*, wenn *einmal* das Gleiche ausdrücken würde, in der Regel als "salopp" wahrgenommen wird. Auf einem Hinweis im Fahrstuhl habe ich eben gelesen

> Sollten Sie einmal im Fahrstuhl eingeschlossen sein ...

Man würde hier nicht *mal* schreiben, da es sich um einen förmlichen Hinweis handelt.